# Running Vault on Kubernetes with Tailscale

Tags: kubernetes, vault, tailscale

I followed [this tutorial](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-raft-deployment-guide) to deploy vault on a kubernetes cluster.

Here is the override-values.yaml file that I used.

```
server:
  dev:
    enabled: true
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    ingressClassName: "tailscale"
    annotations: {}
```

As you can see the 2 changes I made is to make it dev and to create a tailscale ingress.

Everything appears to create correctly. When I try and do vault status I get the error:

```
Error checking seal status: Get "https://<private url>/v1/sys/seal-status": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

When I look at the pod log there are 2 things that stand out to me that don't make sense.

```
Listener 1: tcp (addr: "[::]:8200", cluster address: "[::]:8201", max_request_duration: "1m30s", max_request_size: "33554432", tls: "disabled")
```

and

```
$ export VAULT_ADDR='http://[::]:8200'
```

It seems like there should be information populated for the VAULT_ADDR or the listener addr.

Just assume that I'm a complete newb when it comes to networking.